# How can I validate text from given word

Tags: jquery

How can i check if text begin with ABCxx or ABCxxxx return true . tried using contains or attribue value but all return true

```
<input id="uxPromoCode" name="uxPromoCode" value="" class="form-input">

if("#uxPromoCode:contains('ABC')" ){ // $("#uxPromoCode[value^='ABC']")
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'TRUE CODE', 
    });
}else{
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'FALSE CODE', 
    });
}
```

Example:

```
ABCJ8   -true
ABCJ89K -true
ABCKL   -true
KLHXN   -false
C7HKLOJ -false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.match` here with regex. The way you are currently implementing it is kind of `CSS` attribute and it results in `true` even if it finds `AB` at beginning. Below is the snippet how you can use `.match`

```js
$('.validate').on('click', function() {
  if ($("#uxPromoCode").val().match('^ABC')){
    /*Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'TRUE CODE', 
    });*/
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
    /*Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'FALSE CODE', 
    });*/
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="uxPromoCode" name="uxPromoCode" value="" class="form-input"/>
<input type="button" value="Validate" class="validate"/>
```

Comment: @user3064132 Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Below   `$("#uxPromoCode").val()` will give you value contain in textbox and `indexOf()` function checks whether string **ABC** is present anywhere in textbox value.

```
if($("#uxPromoCode").val().indexOf("ABC") != -1 ){ 
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'TRUE CODE', 
    });
}else{
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'FALSE CODE', 
    });
}
```

To check for start of string is **ABC** use match regex function . The character **^** indicates check at start of string contained in textbox

```
if($("#uxPromoCode").val().match("^ABC")){ 
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'TRUE CODE', 
    });
}else{
    Dialog.msg({
        title: Message.dlg.title4, 
        msg: 'FALSE CODE', 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JS Regular Expression like:

```
var haystack = 'hello world';
var needle = 'he';

if (haystack.indexOf(needle) == 0) {
  // your code if string starts with 'he'
}
```

[Regex Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)